# CSS: Avoiding collapsing margins with list bullets and floats

Tags: css

```
<h3><img src="image.png" width="124" height="124" alt="" style="float: left;"/>This is a heading</h3>
This is text.
<ol>
<li>A list Item</a>
</li><li>Another list item</a>
</li><li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/TVN.cl">Another list item with a link</a>
</li>
</ol>
```

I have an image I want to float at the left of some text content. I notice the bullets on ordered and unordered list collapse with the float, and adding a margin or padding to the image don't add any effect. Is there any clean way to mantain the list margin while retaining the default number and bullets?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

put a margin on your ol tag and make it move going right

```
<h3><img src="image.png" width="124" height="124" alt="" style="float: left;"/>This is a heading</h3>
This is text.
<ol style="margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
<li>A list Item</a>
</li><li>Another list item</a>
</li><li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/TVN.cl">Another list item with a link</a>
</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

hi you can define ol float properties as like this

**Css**

```
ol{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give float to your **OL** or you can use this **CSS** :-

```
    ol {
margin:0 0 0 10px;
padding:0px;
float:left;

}

ol li a {
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}
```